# Log4js - Disable logs for http calls

Tags: node.js, log4js-node

I'm using log4js to log messages. For some reason, the logger automatically logs the http calls, and I can't find a way to disable it. Here is my code:

```
    // Initialize the log4js logger by configurations parameters and appenders.
    log4js.configure({
        appenders: {
            app: {
                type: 'file',
                filename: 'logs/app.log',
                pattern: '-yyyy-MM-dd',
                maxLogSize: LOGS_FILES_MAXIMUM_SIZE
            },
            mq: {
                type: '@log4js-node/rabbitmq',
                host: LOG_SERVER_HOST_ADDRESS,
                port: LOG_SERVER_HOST_PORT,
                username: LOG_SERVER_USERNAME,
                password: LOG_SERVER_PASSWORD,
                routing_key: LOG_SERVER_ROUTING_KEY,
                exchange: LOG_SERVER_EXCHANGE_NAME,
                mq_type: 'direct',
                durable: true
            }
        },
        categories: {
            default: { appenders: ['app'], level: LogLevel.ALL },
            development: { appenders: ['app'], level: LogLevel.ALL },
            production: { appenders: ['app', 'mq'], level: LogLevel.ALL }
        }
    });

    this.log = log4js.getLogger('production');
```

and in app.js

```
this.app.use(log4js.connectLogger(log4js.getLogger('production'), { level: 'off' }));
```

For some reason the logger automatically log messages like this:

> [2019-06-19T16:02:16.182] [OFF] development - ::1 - - "POST
> /api/log/logMessage HTTP/1.1" 200 2
> "http://localhost:3000/?recording-session-id=b983cb82-4812-4c43-87b3-a17e7ed1f6b4&environment=data-center"
> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.90 Safari/537.36"
> [2019-06-19T16:02:16.182] [OFF] development - ::1 - - "OPTIONS
> /api/stream/getStreamData HTTP/1.1" 204 0
> "http://localhost:3000/?recording-session-id=b983cb82-4812-4c43-87b3-a17e7ed1f6b4&environment=data-center"
> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.90 Safari/537.36"
> [2019-06-19T16:02:16.189] [OFF] development - ::1 - - "POST
> /api/stream/getStreamData HTTP/1.1" 200 999
> "http://localhost:3000/?recording-session-id=b983cb82-4812-4c43-87b3-a17e7ed1f6b4&environment=data-center"
> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.90 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code it had to do with the following lines in app.js:

```
const logger = require('morgan');
app.use(logger('dev'));
```

I deleted these lines so as to only use log4js, an not Morgan.